# Convergence of complex mercator series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm trying to find out for which $|z|=1$ the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{}\frac{z^n}{n}$$
converges. It diverges for $z=1$ (harmonic series) and converges for $z=-1$ (alternating harmonic series). I now know that this is the Taylor series for $-log(1-z)$ which doesn't really help me (although it was interesting to find out)?

I found proofs that the series converges for all $|z|=1$ except for this single $z=1$, but we're asked to proof convergence without using test methods we didn't learn (Dirichlet's test, Abel's test) and therefore are not allowed to use.
Have you got any hints on how to get to the wanted result more "heuristically"?

Comment: Is it unbelievable that you have the good idea of multiplying with $1-z$ yourself?

Comment: You mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{}\frac{z^n}{n}=-ln(1-z)$ multiplied with $1-z$? I don't really see how that would help me, but maybe I just can't see the wood for the trees and should go to bed for now.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you shall consider complex $z$? If the exercise concerns only real $z$, the case is simple. If you are asked to prove convergence on the entire unit circle except $1$ without Dirichlet's etc. test, I don't really see how you could do that without effectively proving a special [admittedly easier than the general] case of such a test.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. Well, in a way I do. You consider the difference between partial sums of the series.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure it's complex $z$, the entire unit circle.

Comment: Well, the difference between $n-1$ and $n$ partial sums is simply the summand $\frac{z^n}{n}$

Comment: Not just the difference between consecutive partial sums. You need to show that for every fixed $z$ (on the unit circle except $1$) the sequence $(s_m(z))_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence. It's easy to show that $\bigl((1-z)s_m(z)\bigr)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the idea, but am I allowed to just multiply with $(1-z)$?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out when you can just do that if you think about it for a while.

Comment: Ok, so multiplying by $1-z$ negates the sum which is ok as I use the absolute value (of the difference) in Cauchy's criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Root criteria gives you:
$$\sqrt[n]{\lvert \frac{z^n}{n}\rvert} = t $$
with $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]n = 1$ you get
$\lvert z \rvert = t$

Root criteria now says if $t \lt 1$, the series converges and for $t \gt 1$ the series diverges. For $t=1$ the root criteria does not apply, but for $t=1$ only the cases $z=1$ and $z=-1$ exist for which you already know what happens

Comment: The OP considers _complex_ $z$, where $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ offers far more possibilities.